# Subbase for initial topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

For an index set $I$, there shall be topological spaces $(Y_i,\tau_i)$ with a subbase $S_i$ and mappings $f_i:X\rightarrow Y_i$ for any $i\in I$. Let $\tau$ be the initial topology with respect to $(f_i)_{i\in I}$.

> Is $S=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{f_i^{-1}(U):U\in S_i\}$ a subbase for the initial topology?

I know that $S'=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{f_i^{-1}(U):U\in \tau_i\}$ is a subbase and clearly $S\subseteq S'$. Furthermore, for any $U_i\in\tau_i$ there are index sets $J_i$ and finite $K_i$ and $U_{j,k}\in S_i$, such that

$$U_i=\bigcup_{j\in J_i}\bigcap_{k\in K_i}U_{j,k}$$

and the preimage could be rewritten as

$$f_i^{-1}(U_i)=\bigcup_{j\in J_i}\bigcap_{k\in K_i}f_i^{-1}(U_{j,k})$$

Let $V$ be a proper open set in the initial topology. Then, I know, there exists an index set $M$, a finite index $N$ and sets $V_{m,n}\in S'$, such that

$$V=\bigcup_{m\in M}\bigcap_{n\in n}V_{m,n}$$

and these can, with the preparation from above (and very sloppy notation), somehow be rewritten as

$$V=\bigcup_{m\in M}\bigcap_{n\in N}\bigcup_{j\in J_i}\bigcap_{k\in K_i}f_i^{-1}(U^{m,n}_{j,k})$$

But now I wonder:

> Is this really still a union of finite intersections? Or can it be rewritten as union of finite intersections of elements of S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is $S=\cdots$ a subbase for the initial topology?

Yes. When you write: $$V=\bigcup_{m\in M}\bigcap_{n\in N(m)}\bigcup_{j\in J}\bigcap_{k\in K(j)}f_{i(j,k)}^{-1}(U_{j,k}^{m,n})$$(I've included $f_{i(j,k)}^{-1}$ to show that $i$ will depend, perhaps, on the $j,k$) you've shown $V$ is open in the topology generated by $S$. For each $\bigcap_{k\in K(j)}\cdots$ is open in $S$, so each $\bigcup_{j\in J}\cdots$ is open in $S$, etc.

Another way to realise this would be to endow $X$ with the topology generated by $S$ and ask yourself if this space has the correct characteristic property (functions $Z\to X$ are continuous iff. every $Z\to X\to Y_i$ is continuous). This holds, for a function is continuous if you can show the preimage of any element of the subbase is open.

Comment: Thank you! I was worried that $\cup\cap\cup\cap$ must be rewritten into $\cup\cap$. But clearly any topology, which contains these $f_i^{-1}(U_{j,k}^{m,n})$, also just contains $V=\cup\cap\cup\cap f_i^{-1}(U_{j,k}^{m,n})$. So it's a topology, which makes any $f_i$ continuous. But now I wonder: Why is it not bigger than the initial topology?

Comment: Oh, isn't the generated topology by any collection of open sets just a subset of the topology? I mean: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection of open sets of a topology $\tau$. Then the generated topology of $\mathcal{B}$ must be subset of $\tau$, right?

Comment: @user408858 Yes, that's right. You can formally define "generated topology" as the intersection of all topologies containing those sets. If $\tau$ is a topology, the topology generated by any subset of $\tau$ is necessarily contained in $\tau$ (is necessarily a "coarser" topology than $\tau$)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. Things are clear to me now.

Comment: @user408858 no worries